# Asp.net validation controls with client side validation in js not working properly

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net required field validator controls in my page and i will use js confirm dialog box, if user click on cancel button then reset all dropdowns of page .
then 
asp.net validation not working. i also use Page_ClientValidate() method in js function.

"after cancel confirmation i will try to save next records but this time validation not fire"

if i set DisplayMode Dynamic or static of validator then  its working fine.

in case of DisplayMode is none its not working.

Please guide me where i am wrong.

kaushal

Comment: plz provide some code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a return function, while calling a JavaScript function, then you should remove the `return` keyword:

For example:

```
OnClientClick="t();"
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me when using ASP.NET 4.5. Turns out that there was a setting which I had to do in Web.config to make it work in asp.net 4.5.
A workaround was to manage `Page.IsValid` in each postback.

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```